# Javascript OCR tesseract.js recognize and copy number after spaces

Tags: javascript, tesseract

i want to use tesseract.js libaray to recognize a string like ("رقم العداد") and alert the number that is written after the string like (7038842   رقم العداد) << as you see i want to alert the number after the string from a png picture and copy another number from the picture ("نقطة الخدمة") this is what i have tried and it works fine if the [ text.match ] string was [القراءة] but if i change it to ("رقم العداد") or ("نقطة الخدمة") no alert pops up and gives me this error on console

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')
> at (index):25:63

code :-

```
Tesseract.recognize(
        'Uff.png',
        'ara',
  { logger: m => console.log(m) }
).then(({ data: { text } }) => {
    
    var number = 'رقم العداد'; or /*'نقطة الخدمة'*/
    var result = text.match(new RegExp(number + '\\s+(\\w+)'))[1];
    alert(result);
})
    </script>
```

picture or image link :-
[image: picture]

Answer (score 1):

[You can test on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dqvtbx13/83/)

After some testing and observation for the same problem on **Jsfiddle**. It is the place where I can say that your problem is with the detected text where the **tesseract** fails to detect some Arabic letters as they are.

In order to solve this, you have to make sure from the strings output and use the same string to get your numbers.

For instance, in the example above I intended to get the number after matching the string

**معرف العقار** but **tesseract** does not give the same string. Rather, it gives **محر العفار** so in such a case you have to filter with respect to this and **not** the correct text.

```
var number = 'محر العفار';
var res = text.match(new RegExp(number + '\\s+(\\w+)'))[1];
```

This is the picture on the web that I am testing [image](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTaeCUEkFvyRlUzR7iy90dW_wm6oz3hCdWWRPyqaUx_oNfnY1uEOuUp2M8SNN-5J-K2R4Q&usqp=CAU)

Comment: Thanks for your help and I have a question is there is a way to know the filter string I mean the (محر العفار) string

Comment: I don’t think that there is a way, other than executing the OCR once and seeing the detected text strings, and then using them to filter out wanted numbers!

Comment: as you said mohamad i tried to copy each detected text string like ('رم العداد') and its giving the right number with no problems but the other string ('ننطة الخدمة') doesn't give any thing ```const info = ['ننطة الخدمة','رم العداد','القراءة'];
    for(k=0;k<info.length;k++){
    var result = text.match(new RegExp(info[0] + '\\s+(\\d+)'))[1];
    alert(result);``` what i'm missing ? this is the console log when detecting the word ```ننطة الخدمة | 200135644```

Comment: Did you check first if the number `200135644` is outputting correctly in the whole text?
Also, could you provide me with the same .png file so I can try it!

Comment: Try this as well ant let me know the output `var res = text.substring(text.value.indexOf('ننطة الخدمة'));`

Comment: This is the image url https://ibb.co/JtfBPrk